# Meteor regex on field which may not exist

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

I am preparing a query like this inside a publication (Meteor.pulish)

```
let regex = new RegExp( search, 'i' );
query = {
    $and: [
      {someCondtion: true},
      {$or: [

        { name: regex },
        { surname: regex },
        { email: regex }

      ]}
    ]
  };
return Something.find(query);
```

This is working as expected.

Now I add field which can be matched by the same regex, only difference is that this field may or may not exist in all documents:

```
query = {
    $and: [
      {someCondtion: true},
      {$or: [

        { name: regex },
        { surname: regex },
        { email: regex },
        { maybeField: regex}            
      ]}
    ]
  };
```

The last condition is ignored, I've tried various combination of the following at no avail:

```
{ maybeField: {$exists: true, $eq: regex}}
```

or:

```
{$and:[
     {maybeField:{$exists:true}}.
     {maybeField: regex}
}
```

The worst part is that when I use such variations in the mongo console, it works as expected..!!

Comment: Can you post your sample collection where the query doesn't work

Comment: Does [this mongo regexp article](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#behavior) help you to solve your problem?